# Range of $I + A$ where $A$ is a compact operator on a Hilbert space.

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $A$ be a linear compact operator on a Hilbert space $H$.

> Prove that the range of $A + I$ is a closed subspace of $H$.

I do not know where to start. Could you give me some tips please.

Comment: Show that the range is the orthogonal complement to the kernel of the adjoint

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks, I will try!

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, that doesn't really make things easier. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like the kernel being finite dimensional helps.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom How do you see that the kernel is finite dimensional?

Comment: If it's not, note that the restriction of $A$ to that kernel is not compact.  In particular, $-I$ fails to be compact over any infinite dimensional space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is valid both in a Banach space and in a Hilbert space. In a Banach space it would rely
on  $Z=\ker(I+A)$ being finite dimensional and therefore admitting a closed complement $G$, i.e. $H=Z\oplus G$. In a Hilbert space (as remarked by the OP) you may simply choose  $G=Z^\perp$, the orthogonal complement to the closed subspace $Z$.

It then suffices to show that $F=(I+A)G$ is closed. Thus let $y\in \overline{F}$ we need to show that  there is $x\in G$ with $(I+A)x=y$. Since $y\in \overline{F}$ there is a sequence $x_n\in G$ so that $y_n=(I+A)x_n\rightarrow y$.

Suppose first that the sequence $(x_n)$ admits a bounded subsequence. Then $Ax_n$ admits a convergent subsequence $Ax_{n_k}\rightarrow z$ so that $x_{n_k}=y_{n_k}-A x_{n_k}\rightarrow x$ is convergent as well. As $G$ is closed $x\in G$ and by continuity $(I+A)x=y$.

If on the other hand $|x_n|\rightarrow \infty$ then $e_n=x_n/|x_n|\in G$ is of norm one and $(I+A)e_n\rightarrow 0$. Using compactness we see as before that there is a convergent subsequence $e_{n_k}\rightarrow z\in Z=\ker(I+A)$. But $e_{n_k} \rightarrow z\in G$ as $G$ was closed. Contradiction.

Comment: How do you see that the kernel is finite dimensional?

Comment: If it is not then you may find a sequence $e_n\in Z$ of norm 1 and with $|e_n-e_m|\geq 1/2$. But $e_n=-A e_n$ means that $e_n$ should have a convergent subsequence which it manifestly can not have. (you may have a look at Riesz' Lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz's_lemma )

Comment: Thank you! But I just want to precise one more thing. Why is it enough to show, that if $(I + A)x_n \to 0$ then $x_n \to 0$ to prove, that $(I+A)G$ is closed. I am sorry for being meticulous, but I don't know the theory of compact operators

Comment: I don't understand really how do you use the fact, that $H$ is a Hilbert space. Compact operators are bounded and hence continuous. Therefore $I + A$ is also continuous. This implies that $Z = ker(I+A)$ is a closed subspace of $H$. If $Z$ is a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$, then $H = Z \oplus Z^{\perp} = Z \oplus G$. But for any closed subset $U$ of an inner product space $U^{\perp}$ is a closed subspace. In particular $G = Z^{\perp}$ is also closed. What is wrong with my argumentation?

Comment: That's fine. Thanks for the remark. I thought of the Banach space case. Indeed in Hilbert space there is the simple way you indicate to get the complement. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $N = \ker(I + A)$ is finite dimenisional, and therefore closed.  It follows that the induced map
$$
(I + A)^{\sim} : H/N \to H
$$
is an injective map from a Banach space.  In order to prove that its range is closed, it suffices to show that there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that $\|(I + A)^\sim x\| \geq C\|x\|$.

Suppose to the contrary that no such constant exists.  It would follow that there exists a sequence of vectors $(x_k)_{k \in \Bbb N} \subset H/N$ such that $\|x_k\| = 1$, but $\|x_k\| \to 0$.  Using these vectors, we can build a sequence $(y_k)$ in the unit ball of $H$ such that $Ay_k$ fails to have a convergent subsequence, which means that $A$ fails to be compact.